# Wifi sync with core data library style

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, synchronization

I'm new at wifi sync, where do I start on how to wifi sync a core data library between iPhone and mac apps ? Require a merge sync, no overwrite.

Comment: Are you talking about iCloud sync?

Comment: No, sync through wifi without iCloud. Don't know if its possible though, I was thinking something by the lines of merge policies or something, but don't know where to start. I do have iCloud sync, but a lot of users think that its not private.

Comment: Explain to your users why iCloud is private, and move on. Don't spend your time cooking up a database sync protocol and algorithm for no good reason. (If I'm misunderstanding your needs here, you need to make the question a lot more detailed.)

Comment: No thats about it, but I thought that there were no need for a sync algorithm. More like just using merge procedures from one NSManagedObjectContext to another?

Comment: "Wifi sync" by itself doesn't mean anything to anyone. You need to say a lot more, precisely, about what you want to have happen, in most possible circumstances. What "wifi"? What's the connection between devices?

Comment: It's a bummer for me to decide to -1 this high bounty (!) question (and thanks for making a valuable-enough bounty for people to really want to invest time in helping you), but it really should be edited to add more detail so you can get the answer you're really looking for.  You don't want to use iCloud?  Do you want the Macintosh app to be a "server" or have some service for your iPhone (on the same WiFi network) to connect to?  How about Bonjour?

Comment: Its a free internet Michael you vote as you see fit. As I posted, I'm new at wifi sync, If I new exactly what I was looking for I would have specified it. I've seen apps that allow sync through wifi, but only file based, not core data. And from what Abdur kindly posted, I'm guessing Core Data Sync would only be possible through a Web Server, not between peer to peer wifi. I already have iCloud activated and working. But some users don't like iCloud or any cloud service, for whatever their reasons. Just trying to see if there were other options.